# Emails from VPS go to Hotmail Junk folder

Tags: email, vps, spam, hotmail

Everything I have tried failed. I cannot send from my vps to hotmail inbox folder.
SPF and DKIM are set and working
www.mail-tester.com / web-NFXHGo 10/10
You can see email full headers here http://pastebin.com/CSnFrn6L
Gmail, yahoo, yandex, godaddy and other major email providers accept my emails at inbox
I am on JMRP and SNDS
I have tried many types of content. Plaint text, html, valid content emails
I got that IP a few days ago. It was blacklisted my hotmail.
I asked them to remove the ban but the junk remained which is almost the same to me.
I do not want to use another service like mailchimp or smtp servers.
I do not want to "train" for months hotmail to see that my mails are not spam and loose $$$ in the process.
I have used twice this form support.live.com / eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl3&ct=eformts
but I am pretty sure that the answers are given by a bot

What can i Do more to get to the inbox of my clients?
If I get a new IP am I going to fall on the same dread road?

Comment: I know its an old question but at least you are getting em in the spam folder, i ain't even getting them. (only in hotmail) using a VPS and i'm out of ideas. did you find a solution user?